# How can I design for iOS6 and iOS7

Tags: xcode, ios7, ios6.1

I currently have Xcode v4.6.3 and a 4S device running iOS6. I would like to design for iOS6 as I know there are other people out there like myself who have not updated. Of course, I plan on developing for iOS7 as well and will be updating to Xcode 5, but I want to make sure I will be able to develop for iOS6 in Xcode 5 before updating to it.

I read a few other questions that had mixed answers, saying to copy and paste the iPhoneOS6.1.sdk file and select it as the Base SDK when developing in Xcode 5. I believe that's probably somewhat of how it's done, but I'm not positive and it's been a little bit since the release of iOS7 so I wanted to ask here first to make sure.

Comment: You don't really have a choice.  If you want to put an app on the store you have to build it on Xcode 5 for iOS 7

Comment: second @Abizem Also use autolayout if you are going iOS6+ for one. The below answer shows it unchecked. Autolayout takes a little get use to, but well worth learning it since this is going to be how layouts are used going forward. Also it find it very useful, but again, you have to learn it's quirks first.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your Interface Builder Document from xCode

maybe this will help:

[image: Change IB for iOS 6]

Comment: You should really show autolayout being checked here as the poster wants to build for iOS7 as well.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can develop iOS 6 using Xcode 5+, you do not need to replace the base SDK, and if you do so, you wont get iOS 7 looking, so dont do that if you want to develop for iOS 7 as well.

Comment: So how would I develop for iOS6 in Xcode 5 while I'm also developing for iOS7 in the same project?